# Trying to decode php code from unknown format

Tags: php, encoding

I have this code (sample out of 24500 line code is provided below) in php language and I want to use this code in my project but problem is that, It is converted to unknown format.

```html
     $O = array( function($XB0) use (&$O)
    {
        $lej = array( 6323 => "sq", 1630 => "invalid_perfectmoney_account", 1462 => "Lebanon", 1867 => "/<br> Cash Passport Result URL - ", 261 => "alertpay_from_account", 5096 => " + interval 1 hour and deposit_id = ", 7651 => " group by t.id ", 845 => "select email from hm2_users where id = 1", 5952 => "Location: ", 9642 => "]", 3792 => "select username from hm2_users where id = ", 1591 => "update hm2_users set verify = 1 where id = " );
        return $lej[$XB0];
    }

    , 289, 691, 561, 691, function($LBV) use (&$O)
    {
        $b4X = array( 1591 => "zero_amount", 3792 => "l dS of F Y h:i:s A", 1630 => "QXCR58Z29CNWP8GVKDXP", 1867 => "India", 845 => "Define Key String (random string)", 7651 => "actual_amount", 5096 => "k", 261 => "</ns1:Receiver> <ns1:Currency>", 5952 => ") as create_account_date, now() - interval 2 minute > l_e_t as should_count from hm2_users where ", 9642 => "update hm2_users set password = ", 1462 => "Romania", 6323 => ", ip_reg = ", 4683 => "qplans" );
        return $b4X[$LBV];
    }
, 515, 901, 487, 779, function($wjS, $I8j, $Sbx) use (&$O)
{
    if( $I8j[$O[327](7651)] == $O[1299](7651) ) 
    {
        $S3J = 0;
        print " ";
        if( $I8j[$O[90](5096)] != "" ) 
        {
            $S3J = 1;
            $O[703](7651);
            print $O[703](7651);
            $O[161](7651);
            print $I8j[$O[161](7651)];
            $O[1184](7651);
            print $O[1184](7651);
            $O[161](7651);
            print $I8j[$O[161](7651)];
            $O[478](5096);
            print $O[478](5096);
        }

        $O[703](7651);
        print $O[703](7651);
        $O[161](7651);
        print $I8j[$O[161](7651)];
        $O[828](7651);
        print $O[828](7651);
        print ($S3J ? $O[814](7651) : "");
        $O[39](7651);
        print $O[39](7651);
        $O[1043](7651);
        print $I8j[$O[1043](7651)];
        $O[194](5096);
        print $O[194](5096);
        $O[380]($I8j[$O[1016](7651)]);
        print $O[380]($I8j[$O[1016](7651)]);
        $O[99](5096);
        print $O[99](5096);
        if( $S3J ) 
        {
            $O[996](7651);
            print $O[996](7651);
            $O[1043](7651);
            print $I8j[$O[1043](7651)];
            $O[467](7651);
            print $O[467](7651);
            $O[161](7651);
            print $I8j[$O[161](7651)];
            $O[1244](5096);
            print $O[1244](5096);
            $O[161](7651);
            print $I8j[$O[161](7651)];
            $O[1236](7651);
            print $O[1236](7651);
        }

        $O[1063](845);
        print $O[1063](845);
    }
    else
    {
        if( $I8j[$O[327](7651)] == $O[582](5096) ) 
        {
            $O[1189](5096);
            print $O[1189](5096);
            $O[1043](7651);
            print $I8j[$O[1043](7651)];
            $O[103](7651);
            print $O[103](7651);
            $O[380](($I8j[$O[90](5096)] != "" ? $I8j[$O[90](5096)] : $I8j[$O[100](7651)]));
            print $O[380](($I8j[$O[90](5096)] != "" ? $I8j[$O[90](5096)] : $I8j[$O[100](7651)]));
            $O[536](7651);
            print $O[536](7651);
            $O[380]($I8j[$O[1016](7651)]);
            print $O[380]($I8j[$O[1016](7651)]);
            $O[446](7651);
            print $O[446](7651);
        }
        else
        {
            if( $I8j[$O[327](7651)] == $O[793](7651) ) 
            {
                $O[965](5096);
                print $O[965](5096);
                $O[1043](7651);
                print $I8j[$O[1043](7651)];
                $O[888](7651);
                print $O[888](7651);
                foreach( $DSo as $lIx => $RdI ) 
                {
                    print " ";
                    if( $RdI[$O[735](7651)] == 1 ) 
                    {
                        $O[327](5096);
                        print $O[327](5096);
                        print $lIx;
                        $O[937](5096);
                        print $O[937](5096);
                        $O[90](5096);
                        print ($lIx == $I8j[$O[90](5096)] ? $O[352](7651) : "");
                        $O[901](7651);
                        print $O[901](7651);
                        $O[1016](5096);
                        print $RdI[$O[1016](5096)];
                        $O[598](5096);
                        print $O[598](5096);
                    }

                    print " ";
                }
                $O[271](5096);
                print $O[271](5096);
                return NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                if( $I8j[$O[327](7651)] == $O[183](7651) ) 
                {
                    $xb4 = $I8j[$O[183](7651)];
                    if( $xb4 ) 
                    {
                        $xb4($wjS, $I8j, $Sbx);
                        print $xb4($wjS, $I8j, $Sbx);
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}


    , 373, 154, function($x71) use (&$O)
    {
        $Bsd = array( 6357 => "min_user_password_length", 4683 => "\"/>", 3792 => "\"> <input type=hidden name=ureturn value=\"", 1462 => "~/[\\w\\d]+\\.php.*~", 9642 => "crate", 5952 => " to ", 261 => "last_pay_date", 5096 => "on", 7651 => "/_secret_key/", 845 => " from hm2_history group by user_id, ec", 1867 => "%.0", 1630 => "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=", 6323 => "Purse", 1591 => "recipient", 2607 => "last_withdrawals", 2429 => "Russian Federation", 7210 => "use_transaction_code", 4186 => "2 weeks" );
        return $Bsd[$x71];
    }
```

I have two questions from it:

> 1. What php format is this code?
> 2. How to convert it back into readable format?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: It seems to me the php script is encoded.you need the salt to decode it.From where you get the script.If it is working script, then there must be some salt or function to decode it.Search the decode salt.

Comment: that code looks obfuscated. the whole point of obfuscating code is to *prevent* people from reusing or altering the code. usually, obfuscated code is distributed to people who do not have the rights to alter or use it. if you *do* have, though, i'd recommend asking the original author.